# HttpWebRequest for VISA services keeps returning 400

Tags: c#, json, api

I've been stuck for almost a week for now, there is this authorization API for VISA services, which uses a Transaction token and a session token for authentication, for some reason, it returns :

> Remote server error (400) Bad Request.

I've tried almost everything including:

- Json formatting (Commented code)
- Switching to `WebClient` components

And nothing seems to work, this is the code:

```
string statusCode;

string body =
     "{" +
      "\"transactionToken\": \"" + transactionToken + "\"," +
      "\"sessionToken\": \"" + sessionToken + "\"" +
     "}";

string requestURL = "https://devapice.vnforapps.com/api.authorization/api/v1/authorization/web/{MyMerchantId}";
string id = "xxxxxx";
string password = "yyyyyyy";
string respuesta = "";

try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestURL) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Accept = "application/json";

    var requestStringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
    request.GetRequestStream().Write(requestStringBytes, 0, requestStringBytes.Length);

    request.Headers["Authorization"] = GetBasicAuthHeader(id, password);
    request.Headers["VisaNet-Session-Key"] = sessionToken;

    /*   
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        var json =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            transactionToken = transactionToken,
            sessionToken = sessionToken
         }, Formatting.Indented);

        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }
    */

    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {

        statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        respuesta = readStream.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    using (WebResponse response = ex.Response)
    {
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;

        using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data);
            respuesta = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

There is a previous and first API which creates a Session Key for the rest of the season, I stored this session Key in a Session variable, what could be going on?, I've read a lot of the similar cases here, and tried to apply the best of them without luck.

The `GetBasicAuthHeader` function is a custom function for putting up a Basic Authentication Header which works correctly for the first API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably just as the response is telling you.  Your current code isn't making sure that all the data is flushed when you make the request.

If you wrap the request stream and `StreamWriter` in `using` statements, then the flush will happen when the objects are disposed:

```
string statusCode;

string body =
     "{" +
      "\"transactionToken\": \"" + transactionToken + "\"," +
      "\"sessionToken\": \"" + sessionToken + "\"" +
     "}";

string requestURL = "https://devapice.vnforapps.com/api.authorization/api/v1/authorization/web/{MyMerchantId}";
string id = "xxxxxx";
string password = "yyyyyyy";
string respuesta = "";

try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestURL) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Accept = "application/json";

    using(var rs = request.GetRequestStream()){
        using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(rs)){
            sw.Write(body);
        }
    }
    request.Headers["Authorization"] = GetBasicAuthHeader(id, password);
    request.Headers["VisaNet-Session-Key"] = sessionToken;



    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {

        statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
        using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()){
            respuesta = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    using (WebResponse response = ex.Response)
    {
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;

        using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data);
            respuesta = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

If this doesn't work, examine the HTTP request with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and make sure it matches any specification for the service.

Comment: it's still telling me that there is StatusCode=400, StatusDescription=Bad Request.

Comment: I tried with another VISA Credentials and your improvements work correctly.